# Mocking functions of a class whose object is made inside the __init__ method in another class

Tags: python, pytest, init, pytest-mock

```
import DBClass

class A:
    def __init__:
        self.__db_obj = DBClass()

    def func1():
        data = self.__db.obj.func2()
        return data
```

Above is the class I have written and I want to test the func1 method. For that I have to mock the `func2` method which is actually a method in the class `DBClass` for which I have created the object in the `__init__` method of `class A`.

```
def test_func1:
    mocker.patch("temp.A.__init__", return_value=None)
    mocker.patch("temp.DBClass.func2", return_value={'data1': key1})
    response = A().func1()
    assert response == {'data1': key1}
```

Above is the test function that I have written.

The error I get is :

```
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '_A__db_obj'
```

Can anyone please explain why this happening

Comment: Why are you doing `mocker.patch("temp.A.__init__", return_value=None)`?

Comment: If you patch the `__init__` then it won't run and your attributes won't get assigned, hence the attribute error. Just remove that